# Update window after ScrollWindow(). WinAPI

Tags: winapi

I want to scroll my window, but when i do that, the previous image remains. How can i fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

My code, maybe there are some problems:

```css
switch (LOWORD(wParam))
  {
  case SB_LINEDOWN:
   iVScrollInc = 1;
   break;
  case SB_LINEUP:
   iVScrollInc = -1;
   break;
  case SB_THUMBTRACK:
   iVScrollInc = HIWORD(wParam) - iVScrollPos;
   break;
  default:
   iVScrollInc = 0;
   break;
  }
  
  iVScrollInc = max(-iVScrollPos, min(iVScrollInc, iVScrollMax - iVScrollPos));
  if (iVScrollInc != 0)
  {
   iVScrollPos += iVScrollInc;

   ScrollWindow(hWnd, 0, -cyChar * iVScrollInc, NULL, NULL);
   SetScrollPos(hWnd, SB_VERT, iVScrollPos, TRUE);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
  }
```

EDIT (i cant paste all my code because of stackoverflow writes me that i have more code that describing of my question)

```css
case WM_PAINT:{
  PAINTSTRUCT ps;
  HDC hDc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
  for (int i = 0 ; i < buffer.size(); ++i)
    TextOut(hDc, 20, 20 + i*cyChar, buffer[i].c_str(), buffer[i].length());
  EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
  return 0;
 }
 
// buffer - is std::vector<std::string>
// cyChar - is height of symbols
```

Comment: The code probably doesn't erase the window properly.   WNDCLASSEX.hbrBackground member by default.

Comment: Could you explain, please ?

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i = 0 ; i < buffer.size(); ++i)`, it shouldn't be `buffer.size()`. 
Add `int iPaintEnd = min(buffer.size(), iVscrollPos + ps.rcPaint.bottom / cyChar);` Change to `for (int i = 0 ; i < iPaintEnd ; ++i)`

Besides, you should use `std::vector<std::wstring> buffer`.

Here is my code, you need refer to it.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int  cxChar, cxCaps, cyChar, cxClient, cyClient, iMaxWidth,
        iVscrollPos, iVscrollMax;
    HDC         hdc;
    int         i, y, iPaintBeg, iPaintEnd, iVscrollInc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    TEXTMETRIC  tm;

    switch (iMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

        GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
        cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
        cxCaps = (tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1 ? 3 : 2) * cxChar / 2;
        cyChar = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;

        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        iMaxWidth = 40 * cxChar + 22 * cxCaps;
        return 0;

    case WM_SIZE:
        cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
        cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);

        iVscrollMax = max(0,buffer.size() + 2 - cyClient / cyChar);
        iVscrollPos = min(iVscrollPos, iVscrollMax);

        SetScrollRange(hwnd, SB_VERT, 0, iVscrollMax, FALSE);
        SetScrollPos(hwnd, SB_VERT, iVscrollPos, TRUE);

        return 0;

    case WM_VSCROLL:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case SB_TOP:
            iVscrollInc = -iVscrollPos;
            break;

        case SB_BOTTOM:
            iVscrollInc = iVscrollMax - iVscrollPos;
            break;

        case SB_LINEUP:
            iVscrollInc = -1;
            break;

        case SB_LINEDOWN:
            iVscrollInc = 1;
            break;

        case SB_PAGEUP:
            iVscrollInc = min(-1, -cyClient / cyChar);
            break;

        case SB_PAGEDOWN:
            iVscrollInc = max(1, cyClient / cyChar);
            break;

        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            iVscrollInc = HIWORD(wParam) - iVscrollPos;
            break;

        default:
            iVscrollInc = 0;
        }
        iVscrollInc = max(-iVscrollPos,
            min(iVscrollInc, iVscrollMax - iVscrollPos));

        if (iVscrollInc != 0)
        {
            iVscrollPos += iVscrollInc;
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, 0, -cyChar * iVscrollInc, NULL, NULL);
            SetScrollPos(hwnd, SB_VERT, iVscrollPos, TRUE);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        }
        return 0;



    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        iPaintBeg = max(0, iVscrollPos + ps.rcPaint.top / cyChar - 1);
        iPaintEnd = min(buffer.size(),
            iVscrollPos + ps.rcPaint.bottom / cyChar);

        for (i = iPaintBeg; i < iPaintEnd; i++)
        {
            y = cyChar * (1 - iVscrollPos + i);

            TextOut(hdc, 0, y,
                buffer[i].c_str(),
                buffer[i].length());


            SetTextAlign(hdc, TA_LEFT | TA_TOP);
        }

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Charlz Petsold. I read it now. It seems to me that i wrote my code like his, but i dont understand why my code is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I can, but really sorry, I don't have my laptop. Later

Comment: Why we write SetTextAlign after TextOut?

Comment: Refer to [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-settextalign) of SetTextAlign

Comment: It works with `iPaintBeg` and `iPaintEnd` but i dont understand why do we need ScrollWindow if `iPaintBeg` and `iPaintEnd` tell us from which element of `buffer` start to draw. What if i want to scroll by pixel , not by height of font

Comment: If the caret is in the window being scrolled, `ScrollWindow` automatically hides the caret to prevent it from being erased and then restores the caret after the scrolling is finished. The caret position is adjusted accordingly.
The area uncovered by `ScrollWindow` is not repainted, but it is combined into the window's update region. The application eventually receives a `WM_PAINT` message notifying it that the region must be repainted. To repaint the uncovered area at the same time the scrolling is in action, call the `UpdateWindow` function immediately after calling `ScrollWindow`.